# How do I split by "/" delimiters using index in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, indexoutofboundsexception, delimiter

In one DataFrame some columns are in the DataFrame. I want to column value to split by "/" using index. Below are the list of columns where i want to split the data.

```
Eg:- split_columns = ['Fuel', 'Air Pollution Score', 'City MPG', 'Hwy MPG', 'Cmb MPG', 'Greenhouse Gas Score']
```

If in Fuel contain data then the output should be like "ethanol/gas".

Here is my code-

```
split_columns = ['Fuel', 'Air Pollution Score', 'City MPG', 'Hwy MPG', 'Cmb MPG', 'Greenhouse Gas Score']

for c in split_columns:
  df1[c] = df1[c].apply(lambda x: x.split("/")[0])
  df2[c] = df2[c].apply(lambda x: x.split("/")[1])
```

When i execute above code then i found an error "Index out of range".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with indexing `str[0]` and `str[1]` for select first and second nested lists.

If `/` not exist, output is `NaN` value, not `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
for c in split_columns:
  df1[c] = df1[c].astype(str).str.split("/").str[0]
  df2[c] = df2[c].astype(str).str.split("/").str[1]
```

Comment: Getting this error `Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas`

Comment: @user8487380 - add `.astype(str)`

Comment: @user8487380 -All columns of `split_columns` are filled by strings?

Answer (score 1):

Here it just means that sometimes, there is no `"/"` in the few other columns. So, when there is no `"/"`, split is going to have only one element. But, you are accessing `x.split("/")[1]`. this is causing index error. to fix this, just check if `"/"` is present in the x or just check the length of the split. If its more than 1, it means that there is a `"/"` present.

Comment: How to check the length of split. We're going to take each hybrid row and split them into two new rows - one with values for the first fuel type (values before the "/"), and the other with values for the second fuel type (values after the "/").

Comment: length of split is nothing but `len(x.split("/"))`

Answer (score 0):

It has an index problem:
I found 2 solutions:
1) I split this in 2 for (in 2 cells of Jupyter) and this error is gone.

for c in split_columns:
    df1[c] = df1[c].apply(lambda x: x.split("/")[0])
for c in split_columns:
    df2[c] = df2[c].apply(lambda x: x.split("/")[1])

2) I rename the second index
for c in split_columns:
    df1[c] = df1[c].apply(lambda x: x.split("/")[0])
    df2[c] = df2[c].apply(lambda x: x.split("/")[0])